# If i click on login button in child page both child and parent pages are reloaded

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I am doing resetting password using angular.js and node.js. In the parent page I had clicked on forgot password link then I entered email address. One link will send to that mail.

### login page

[image: login.html]

### forgot-password page

[image: forgot password.html]

After click on my Reset password button I got one email with link to reset-password page.

### Reset-password page

[image: Reset page]

After clicked on link reset-password page opened and I had changed the password, It shows success message.

### Reset-password page

[image: Reset]

After this I clicked on `Go back to login` link then this child page redirected to the login page. At the same time parent page also redirected to the login page from forgot-password page. After I had logged in from child page successfully, in parent page url bar shows like this `http://localhost:3000/pages/auth/login?username=&password=kevin`. It showing my password on parent page url bar.So now I want to do parent page is not redirected.

### login.module

```
(function ()
{
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.pages.auth.login', [])
    .config(config);

/** @ngInject */
function config($stateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider)
{
    $stateProvider.state('app.pages_auth_login', {
        url  : '/pages/auth/login',
        views: {
            'main@'                       : {
                templateUrl: 'app/core/layouts/basic.html'
            },
            'content@app.pages_auth_login': {
                templateUrl: 'app/main/pages/auth/login/login.html',
                controller : 'LoginController as vm'
            }
        }
    });

    $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('app/main/pages/auth/login');
}

})();
```

### reset-password.module

```
(function ()
{
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.pages.auth.reset-password', [])
    .config(config);

/** @ngInject */
function config($stateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider)
{
    $stateProvider.state('app.pages_auth_reset-password', {
        url  : '/pages/auth/reset-password?token',
        views: {
            'main@'                          : {
                templateUrl: 'app/core/layouts/basic.html'
            },
            'content@app.pages_auth_reset-password': {
                templateUrl: 'app/main/pages/auth/reset-password/reset-password.html',
                controller : 'ResetpasswordController as vm'
            }
        }
    });
}

})();
```

### forgot-password.module

```
(function ()
{
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.pages.auth.forgot-password', [])
    .config(config);

/** @ngInject */
function config($stateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider)
{
    $stateProvider.state('app.pages_auth_forgot-password', {
        url  : '/pages/auth/forgot-password',
        views: {
            'main@'                                 : {
                templateUrl: 'app/core/layouts/basic.html'
            },
            'content@app.pages_auth_forgot-password': {
                templateUrl: 'app/main/pages/auth/forgot-password/forgot-password.html',
                controller : 'ForgotPasswordController as vm'
            }
        }
    });

    $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('app/main/pages/auth/forgot-password');
}

})();
```

### api.js

```
router.post('/pages/auth/forgot-password', function(req,res,next){
    var maillist = req.body.email;
    async.waterfall([
        function(done) {
            crypto.randomBytes(20, function(err, buf) {
                var token = buf.toString('hex');
                done(err, token);
            });
        },

        function(token, done) {
            User.findOne({ email : maillist}, function(err, user) {
                if (!user){
                    var message = {
                        message: 'No account with this email address exists.'
                    };
                    done(null, message);
                } else if (token, user, done){
                    user.resetPasswordToken = token;
                    user.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000;           

                    user.save(function(err) {
                        done(err, token, user);
                    });

                    var mailOptions={
                            to : maillist,
                            subject : 'Password Recovery',                  
                            text: 'Dear ' + maillist + ' \n\n' +
                            'You are receiving this because you (or someone else) have requested the reset of the password for your account.\n\n' +
                            'Please click on the following link, or paste this into your browser to complete the process:\n\n' +
                            'http://127.0.0.0:3000/pages/auth/reset-password?' +'token='+ token + '\n\n' +
                            'If you did not request this, please ignore this email and your password will remain unchanged.\n'
                        };
                        transport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
                            if(!error){

                            }
                            transport.close();
                        });
                        var message = {
                            message: 'We have sent a link on ' + maillist + ' to reset your password and you should receive it shortly.'
                        };
                        done(null, message);
                    }
            });
        }

    ], function(err, result){
        if (err) return next(err);
        return res.json({
            result: result.message
        });
    });
});

router.get('/pages/auth/reset-password/:token', function(req, res) {
    User.findOne({ resetPasswordToken: req.query.tkn, resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now() }}, function(err, user) {
        if (!user){
            //req.flash('error', 'Password reset token is invalid or has expired.');
            //return res.redirect('http://127.0.0.0:3000/api/pages/auth/forgot-password');
            return res.json({result: 'Password reset token is invalid or has expired.'});
        }
        return res.redirect('http://127.0.0.0:3000/api/pages/auth/reset-password/:token', {
          user: req.user
        });
    });
});

router.post('/pages/auth/reset-password/:token', function(req, res){
    var tkn = req.body.tkn;
    async.waterfall([
        function(done) {
            User.findOne({ resetPasswordToken: req.body.tkn, resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now() } }, function(err, user) {
                if (!user) {
                    var message = {
                        message: 'Password reset token is invalid or has expired.'
                    };
                    done(null, message);
                }else if (user, done){
                    user.password = req.body.data.newPassword;
                    user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
                    user.resetPasswordExpires = undefined;

                    user.save(function(err) {
                        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                            done(err, user);
                        });
                    });

                    var mailOptions={
                        to :  user.email,
                        subject : 'Your password has been changed',                 
                        text: 'Hello,\n\n'+
                        'This is a confirmation that the password for your account ' + user.email + ' has just been changed.\n'
                    };
                    transport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
                        if(!error){

                        }
                        transport.close();
                    });
                    var message = {
                        message: 'Success! Your password has been changed. Click below link to login.'
                    };
                    done(null, message);
                }
            });
        }
    ], function(err, result){
        if (err) return next(err);
        return res.json({
            result: result.message
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: why no one is answering for this question?